# is root mean square possible to calculate similarity of FFT result?

Tags: java, fft

I need to compare FFT result from audio files,
I have 2 FFT result from 2 audio files..

FFT 1 (sample)

```
-0.16314493488504767 - 0.103707391105263i
0.07863935536550609 - 0.30111206509352917i
0.06753127619272284 + 0.02837438103569126i
```

FFT 2 (sample)

```
-0.006953384463464084 + 0.0291883094944081i
-0.09447919915711694 - 0.22676541801892i
-0.23493813662827812 - 0.07765408995141115i
```

Then I need to calculate the deviation of each real-part point (without imaginer part) from the FFT result then make the result absolute, something like this

```
-0.16314493488504767 - (-0.006953384463464084) 
--> then use Math.abs to get absolute value
```

then sum all the deviation point, and use [Root Mean Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) formula to follow with to get the difference value...

[image: Root Mean Square Formula]

where N is my numbeofFFTPoint and the following x is the sum value of my deviation result.

But then, someone told me to use [Zero crossing rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-crossing_rate) formula to get more accurate result
[image: Zero Crossing rate]

Honestly I don't really understand about Zero Crossing Rate,

**what have I tried :**

I compare the exact same 2 audio files, then get the deviation and sum result --> 0.0  and of course the Root Mean Square Formula result is 0.0 too.. 
since there's no difference between the files the it would return 0.0 right ??

**question**

is it possible just to user Root Mean Square ??
Any advice which formula should I use for this case ?

Thanks :) (*sorry 4 bad explaining*)

Comment: Im assuming FFT is Fast Fourier transform? Beware acronyms

Comment: ohh I'm sorry... Yes it's Fast Fourier transform :)

Comment: While this is clearly related to programming you might find more knowledge with the maths people. The only advise I can offer is test it and see which gives you the better results, if they're the same use the one you're most comfortable with

Comment: @RichardTingle ahh... indeed, so I really need to ask the math people... O_o  
thanks 4 response and advice by the way.. :)

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to determine if some audio is a noisy version of another audio sample (e.g. song identification)?

Comment: Here's an example in Python: https://gist.github.com/endolith/1257010

Comment: Looking at just the differences in the real parts (ignoring the imaginary parts) of the spectrum is very questionable. I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do, but this looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Discrete Fourier Transform is a unitary transform (maybe scaled).  As such, it preserves the Frobenius norm of the signal.  That is essentially the same as the Root Mean Square calculation.

In other words:

```
 rms( x - y ) == C * norm( fft(x) - fft(y) )
```

for an appropriate constant C depending on your fft implementation.

In Matlab or octave, C=1/nfft:

```
 n=8192;
 x=randn(n,2)*[1;j];
 y=randn(n,2)*[1;j];
 sqrt( mean( abs(x-y).^2 ) ) - norm(fft(x) - fft(y)) / n

 ans = -5.3291e-15
```

Comment: thanks for giving explanation and sample..
It helps a lot.. :)